# request.getAttribute returns null after forward

Tags: jsp, servlets

form.html (This is the original form):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Beer Advisor</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Beer Selection Page</h1>
        <form action="BeerSelect.do" method="POST">
            Select bear characteristics
            <p>
            Color:
            <select name="color" size="1">
                <option value="light">light</option>
                <option value="amber">amber</option>
                <option value="brown">brown</option>
                <option value="dark">dark</option>
            </select>
            <br><br>
            <input type="SUBMIT" style="alignment-adjust: central">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Servlet (After clicking "Submit Query" on the original form, control is transferred to the servlet. The servlet adds a List object, which it gets from the BeerExpert java object, and adds it to the request. Then the request object is forwarded to the JSP):

```
package com.example.web;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.example.model.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;

public class BeerSelect extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP
     * <code>GET</code> and
     * <code>POST</code> methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

        try {
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
            String c = request.getParameter("color");
            BeerExpert be = new BeerExpert();
            List brands = be.getBrands(c);

            request.setAttribute("styles", brands);

            RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("result.jsp");
            view.forward(request, response);

        } finally {            

        }
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP
     * <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP
     * <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>
}
```

JSP (Here is where I encounter the issue. In the code below, "styles" is null):

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page  import="java.util.*" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Beer Advisor</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 style="alignment-adjust: central">Beer Recommendations JSP</h1>
        <p>
            <% 
                List styles = (List)request.getAttribute("styles");

                if(styles != null) {
                    Iterator it = styles.iterator();
                    while (it.hasNext()) {
                        out.println("<br>try: " + it.next());
                    }
                }
            %>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

BeerExpert.java (This class is accessed by the Servlet):

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.example.model;
import java.util.*;
/**
 *
 * @author
 */
public class BeerExpert {

    public List getBrands(String color) {
        List brands  = new ArrayList();
        if (color.equals("amber")) {
            brands.add("Jack Amber");
            brands.add("Red Moose");
        }
        else {
            brands.add("Jail Pale Ale");
            brands.add("Gout Stout");
        }
        return (brands);
    }

}
```

The following is my output from the JSP:

```
Beer Recommendations JSP
```

I am using Apache Tomcat.

Why is this happenning? Can someone provide a solution for me?

Answer (score 0):

It sure looks like an exception is being thrown in your BeerExpert.getBrands() method.  That is the only way that the beer list could be empty.

The servlet is definitely being called because we see output from the forwarded JSP.

So it appears appears as if the list is empty.  This could only happen if an exception is thrown.  The only possible cause I see is if the "color" parameter is null.

Are you able to hook up a debugger to your tomcat Java process?  If so, stepping through the servlet code will quickly give you the answer.

Comment: The problem was coming from my web.xml file. I removed the jsp file tag from within the servlet tag and it worked. Thanks though.